# Enforcing in git that topic branches are only created from certain branch

Tags: git, azure-devops

We're using azure devops and git to manage our CI/CD workflow to deploy our application to azure.

We have git branches for each env (canary, test, prod etc), new changed are made by a user creating a topic branch from the prod branch and then creating a PR to the canary branch using a non-fast-forward merge type, this ensure the that other in-flight changes are kept separate.

But we have issues where our users don't always remember to create a new topic branch from the right most branch (prod) which means they can end up pulling other changes through when they didn't mean to - or creating merge conflicts.

Is there a way in either azure devops or in git (which we could create a validation pipeline for) to check that a topic branch was indeed started from the right most branch?

Comment: Git definitely doesn't have the tools to enforce this sort of flow. Azure devops might?

Comment: In Git, the user creates a new branch name locally, from a commit hash ID. They may supply a branch name, or the magic name `HEAD` (or no name or hash ID at all but that *means* `HEAD`) when they do this action, but it's always resolved to a raw hash ID first. Then Git creates the name. Since this happens on the individual user's laptop or other private computer, you literally cannot control this, and should not attempt to do so. Instead, give your users some sort of convenience tool that does whatever you define to be the "right thing". They can then use that to avoid mistakes.

Comment: The part of the process that you *do* control (at least indirectly) is the CI/CD process, and at this point you can insert any *checks* you like, depending on the CI/CD tools available from your CI/CD provider (Git does not have CI/CD built in so that's definitely not Git itself). Run the commits you receive through your checking software, and decide whether to proceed or not; if not, advise the user that they should use your provided tool so that they don't have this problem next time.

Comment: You could add a simple bash/batch/pwsh script to your repo which people could use to initiate certain actions. Or you could configure git flow to understand your branching structure. That way people can use those commands instead of creating a branch directly. Even in your pipeline it's going to be hard to know what branch the current commits originates from especially when it may take a bit of time between branch creation and it big submitted to your CI system.

Comment: I think an ASCII git tree diagram to explain how the various branches are related and an example problem case would improve this question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a build pipeline such as the one below. You could configure this as a
validation build as part of your `canary` branch policy to ensure that `prod` is in the history of your `topic` branches.

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  BranchOfInterest: "origin/prod"

steps:

- checkout: self    
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
    git for-each-ref --contains "$(BranchOfInterest)" | grep ` git rev-parse HEAD `;
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "$(BranchOfInterest) is not in the history of $(Build.SourceBranch). This is not allowed when merging into $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)."
        exit 1;
    fi
  displayName: 'Ensure $(BranchOfInterest) is in the history of $(Build.SourceBranch).'
```

You could also invert this using `--no-contains` to ensure that a certain branch isn't in the history of the topic branch.